# Summarizing/counting multiple binary variables

Tags: r, count, binary, large-data

For the purpose of this question, my data set includes 16 columns (c1_d, c2_d, ..., c16_d) and 364 rows (1-364). This is what it briefly looks like:

```
 c1_d c2_d c3_d c4_d c5_d c6_d c7_d c8_d c9_d c10_d c11_d c12_d c13_d c14_d c15_d c16_d
1     1    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0
2     1    1    0    1    1    1    0    1    1     1     1     0     1     0     0     0
3     1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    0     1     1     0     1     0     1     0
4     0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0
5     1    0    1    1    1    1    0    1    0     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
```

Please note that for example row 1, has five 1s and 11 0s.
This is what I'm trying to do: Basically counting how many rows have how many of the value 1 assigned to them (i.e. by the end of this analysis I want to get something like 20 rows had zero value 1 assigned to them, 33 rows had one value 1 assigned to them, 100 rows had 10 value 1 assigned to them, etc.).

I tried to create a data frame including all rows (364) and columns (16) I needed. I tried using the print.data.frame function, and its results are shown above, but it doesn't give me the number of 0s and 1s per row. I tried using functions such as table, ftable, and xtab, but they don't really work for more than three variables.
I would highly appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Welcome @Naz. `rowSums(df)` gives you the number of 1's for each row. `ncol(df) - rowSums(df)`  also gives the number of 0's for each row as well. Where `df` is the name of your dataframe.

Comment: @maydin Thank you so much for your answer. I tried this as you suggested, and it does give me the number of 0s and 1s per row, but the problem is that since there are so many rows (364), I don't want to categorize these manually. Is there any way these numbers can be summarized? To get something like: 20 rows had zero 1, 10 rows had one 1, 50 rows had two 1, 35 rows had three 1, etc.?

Comment: `table(rowSums(df))`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  transmute(count0 = rowSums(df==0),
         count1 = rowSums(df==1)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  count(name, value)
```

```
name   value     n
   <chr>  <dbl> <int>
 1 count0     5     1
 2 count0     6     1
 3 count0     7     1
 4 count0    11     1
 5 count0    12     1
 6 count1     4     1
 7 count1     5     1
 8 count1     9     1
 9 count1    10     1
10 count1    11     1
```